# How to remove django

Tags: uninstall, django

Running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS i had a testdrive with django from Sources. But now i want to change to latest django 1.6.
So how to remove the older django 1.4.3?

I ask this after going thru the obvious steps because the following
`python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"`
reports still 1.4.3.

Not sure if this 1.4.3 was already an upgrade using a direct download...

So not sure to follow the path which
`python -c "import sys; sys.path = sys.path[1:]; import django; print(django.__path__)"`
reports and delete this folder:
`['/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django']`

Comment: Note: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django is a link to /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django

i now deleted this folder and test the result

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django` is a link to `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django`

I deleted it now.
Was not sure if the process of removing really has to be done manually.

Comment: What procedure?

Comment: @Braiam [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/388047/how-to-remove-django/388882#comment497390_388047) I think. I would move it here so, please let me know if not.